# Выцепить value у элемента с динамическим классом (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь получить значение value у объекта, класс которого меняется динамически, с помощью другого js скрипта. Менять ничего в этом скрипте я не могу.

При клике на любой элемент списка, класс active переходит к нему.
но с помощью find('.active').val() я получаю лишь ошибку.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

```js
var zabor_type = $('.type_zabor').find('.active').val() //
```

```html
<ul class="type_zabor">
    <li class="active list-item" value='0'>Вариант 1</li>
    <li class="list-item" value='1'>Вариант 2</li>
    <li class="list-item" value='2'>Вариант 3</li>
</ul>
```

Каким еще способом можно получить value?

Comment: А если собрать в коллекцию все элементы и проверять через цикл наличие класса у элемента. И совершать какое либо действие  с данным элементом.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка:

Вы задаёте атрибут `value` тегу `<li>` что является некорректным, тк атрибут value может быть только у элементов формы, к примеру, у `<input>`

Если можно изменить разметку, то лучше поменяйте таким образом, `value` замените на `data-value`, ваш код станет таким:

```
<ul class="type_zabor">
    <li class="active list-item" data-value='0'>Вариант 1</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-value='1'>Вариант 2</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-value='2'>Вариант 3</li>
</ul>
```

Что-бы получить активный, потребуется:

```
var zabor_type = $('.type_zabor > .list-item.active').data().value;
```

Если разметку менять нельзя, в силу каких то обстоятельств, то решение будет:

```
var zabor_type = $('.type_zabor > .list-item.active').attr('value');
```